# First test in each test suite fails connecting to the DB

Tags: oracle, ant, jdbc, junit, hudson

We are running more than 2000 junit, Most of the tests connect to an Oracle database with jdbc calls. We have a problem with very few of the tests that can not connect to the DB for some reason. Here is some background:

- We are running the tests in a CI server - `Jenkins`
- Tests are being run by ANT with `<junit>` task with `fork="true"`
- Only few of the tests fail with `Could not connect to database` error, it's not consistent, sometimes they fail and sometimes not.
- **The tests that fail are usually the first tests in each test suite**
- The rest of the tests that also connect to the db do not fail.

So far we have no luck in solving it.
Anyone encountered something similar ?

Here's a stack trace:

```
Error Message

Could not connect to database using the connect string jdbc:oracle:thin:R71/R71@abc.def:1521:DB11g
Stacktrace

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not connect to database using the connect string jdbc:oracle:thin:R71/R71@abc.def:1521:DB11g
    at com.abc.common.dao.JDBCUtils.getThinConnection(JDBCUtils.java:257)
    at com.abc.common.dao.JDBCUtils.getConnection(JDBCUtils.java:115)
    at com.abc.common.dao.JDBCUtils.queryForInt(JDBCUtils.java:714)
    at com.abc.test.utils.MetaDataLanguageDBTest.testMetaDataLanguages(MetaDataLanguageDBTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:428)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at com.abc.common.dao.JDBCUtils.getThinConnection(JDBCUtils.java:254)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:96)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:199)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:211)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:227)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:366)
Standard Error

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:428)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at com.abc.common.dao.JDBCUtils.getThinConnection(JDBCUtils.java:254)
    at com.abc.common.dao.JDBCUtils.getConnection(JDBCUtils.java:115)
    at com.abc.common.dao.JDBCUtils.queryForInt(JDBCUtils.java:714)
    at com.abc.test.utils.MetaDataLanguageDBTest.testMetaDataLanguages(MetaDataLanguageDBTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:421)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:912)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:766)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:96)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:199)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:211)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:227)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:366)
    ... 25 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: Security note: I hope that the server/port is not accessible from the internet, otherwise you have just broadcasted to the entire world how to log on to your database.

Comment: Thanks :) but i've used a fake connect string, made it up.

Comment: Does each test create its own connection or do they use a DataSource?

Comment: @Kevin each test create it's own connection

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is super old, but I just had the same problem. The solution for me was to add the following environment variable to my tests:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom
```

In short, the Oracle JDBC driver uses `/dev/random` by default, which can block if there isn't enough entropy on the system. The full explanation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327220/oracle-jdbc-intermittent-connection-issue).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are running out of connections. I would try using a DataSource backed by a connection pool instead.

Comment: does it explain why the first test always fail and the rest of the tests pass ? what you say might be right, but adapting this method is more complicated for me at this stage. i though it might have to do with the fact that the tests run in `fork="true"`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that point. Yeah, sounds like it's probably not a problem with too many connections.