# Centos7 + Oracle12c driver fails to get connection

Tags: java, sql, oracle, centos7

There seems to be an issue with Centos7 and the ojdbc6 driver that is used for Oracle connections. The connection hangs and or fails resulting in a timeout.  The following is the simplest program I could derive to show this issue:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Test{  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"):
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){System.out.println(e);}    
       Connection conn = null;
       try{
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
       }catch(SQLException e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

The odd thing is this code executes perfectly fine on Centos6.

Comment: @Mureinik it is a timeout issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the JDBC drivers are operating system-dependent. However, for the issue you are facing, you can try setting the JVM property like this:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom
```

Please refer to this issue [Oracle JDBC intermittent Connection Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327220/oracle-jdbc-intermittent-connection-issue).

The issue on connection timeout and its relation with server randomness is mentioned in details there.