# How do I add continuous entropy on a linux server

Tags: java, linux, oracle11g, entropy, ojdbc

Environment:
Headless Linux server
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
2.6.32-573.12.1.e16.x86_64

I have a java(7) program that I run from command line that spawns multiple threads and hits a oracle database simultaneously using ojdbc7.

Intermittently I see connection reset error:

```
 Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
```

exactly as [reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327220/oracle-jdbc-intermittent-connection-issue) and [resolved here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/943911?tstart=0&messageID=3793101).

I tried the following to mitigate the issue:

Add these variations to my command line

- -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom
- -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom
- -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

Tried adding to java.security file

- securerandom.source=file:///dev/urandom
- securerandom.source=file:/dev/../dev/urandom
- securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom

Also tried ojdbc6

But I still see the issue. Which means that even with urandom in use, still there is not enough realtime entropy. Which is understandable, because when I run my java program, everything else is stopped (this is a application server with multiple running jvms, usually. )

I am wondering if there is anything I can do to 'cause' entropy on the server. I have limited access to this server so I am limited in what I can do. This java job is expected to run for a couple of hours, so I can not keep typing on the keyboard etc. May be run a simple program in the background that 'does' something?

Any ideas? I tried rngd command but apparently I do not have permission to use it. Any help greatly appreciated, been stuck with this issue for a while now.

Edit:
I tried to run another java program (using java.awt.Robot) that simulates Keyboard presses continuously during my original program run, but due to limited permissions on the server I wasn't able to get it working. But in general, would that be a good way to ensure some entropy?

Comment: Maybe http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/

Comment: It seems that your urandom setting is not "taking" for some reason; urandom simply does not block. I would investigate the actual open files (maybe with `lsof`) and confirm the actual device in use.

Comment: @chrylis - when I do lsof -p I do not see /dev/urandom. But does that really mean it is not using it? How do I capture if the file is used over a period of time?

Comment: I'd generally try `strace`. Note also that the problem might be on the server if it's not being able to generate random.