# Frequent Connection reset in Spring Jdbc Template

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using JDBC Template to connect to oracle database. Frequently I am getting exception which will disappear after few seconds. When I retry I will be able to execute sql query.

```
2016-09-17 12:34:30.404 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-4] ERROR UserController.getcontactInfo - Error while getting contact info
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Io exception: Connection reset; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:251) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:645) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:680) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at c.s.c.dao.impl.DaoImpl.getContactInfo(DaoImpl.java:109) ~[classes/:na]
    at c.s.c.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.getContactInfo(UserServiceImpl.java:159) ~[classes/:na]
    at c.s.c.controller.user.UserController.getcontactInfo(UserController.java:95) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at c.s.c.login.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:84) [classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:873) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:101) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:112) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:173) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:229) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:458) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:796) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:860) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3381) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3425) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1490) ~[ojdbc6.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "11.1.0.6.0-Production+"]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

My connection pool settings

```
datasource.maxActive=10
datasource.maxIdle=10
datasource.initialSize=5
datasource.maxWait=5000
```

I suspected it be oracle driver issue listed in

[Oracle JDBC intermittent Connection Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327220/oracle-jdbc-intermittent-connection-issue)

https://community.oracle.com/message/3795101

http://www.usn-it.de/index.php/2009/02/20/oracle-11g-jdbc-driver-hangs-blocked-by-devrandom-entropy-pool-empty/

I set following property in jvm.

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom
```

But still it didnt help.

Anyone is facing/faced similar problem?

Comment: Make sure you configure a validation query. The database server will close idle connections after a certain amount of time (configurable on server), so any connection sitting unused in the dbcp pool will go stale. Adding a validation query to the pool configuration will ensure that the connection is checked and reestablished before given to your code.

Comment: Could you describe in a bit more detail what do you mean by "frequently"?

Comment: It happens very randomnly. I would say 10 times in a day and my application is not so heavy. 10-20 requests per hour.Thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug reference so I'll post my comment as an answer.

See [Java bug 6202721](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6202721)

Seems even if you explicitly request `/dev/urandom` Java silent replaces it with `/dev/random`, which can't keep up with entropy generation on Linux.

Try specifying `/dev/./urandom` instead.  The substitution happens based on the explicit string value and if you want to really *force* `urandom` you have to provide an alternate form that doesn't match the string but still resolves to the same path.

Comment: But looks like this it fixed in Java 6. I am using Java 8. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The bug was closed as "not an issue" and nothing was done.